# Only first page opens up after the nav bar on one-page fixed nav website

Tags: html, css

http://codepen.io/abravo227/pen/MbzxBW

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" media="screen" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/badges/js/profile.js" async defer></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navWrapper">
  <nav id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
</div><!--End of Nav-->
  <a id ="home" class="smooth"></a>
  <div id="page1">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <h1 class="firstTitle text-primary text-center">Hi, I'm First Last</h1>
        <h3 class="subTitle text-center">The most interesting man in the world</h3>
        <img src="imgage.jpg" class="firstImg center-block img-rounded img-responsive" alt="First Last Resume">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 linkedIn"><div class="LI-profile-badge"  data-version="v1" data-size="medium" data-locale="en_US" data-type="horizontal" data-theme="dark" data-vanity="#linkedin-info"><a class="LI-simple-link" href='www.linkedin.com'>First Last</a></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="quote">
      <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-4"><blockquote><p><em>"Striving for excellence every day, in everything that I do."</em></p><footer>First Last</footer></blockquote></div>
      <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div><!--End of Page 1-->
    <a id ="about" class="smooth"></a>
    <div id="page2">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 aboutMe"><i class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h1>About Me</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--end of page 2-->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height:50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: gray;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#nav ul {
  display: inline;
}

#nav li {
  display: inline;
}

#nav a {
  padding: 14px 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


#nav a:hover {
  background-color: #0C5DA5;
}

#nav a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: yellow;
}



blockquote {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#quote {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.linkedIn {
  top: 30px;
  float: right;
}
.firstTitle{
  font-family: lobster, monospace;
  color: blue;
}

.subTitle {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  font-family: lobster, monospace;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.firstImg {
  position: relative;
  width: 264px;
  height: 296px;
  border-color: gray;
  border-width: 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  top: 0px;
}

#page1 {
  padding-top: 40px;
  height: 800px;
}

#page2 {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Would anyone be able to help me understand why my second page does not open up directly under the nav bar but instead a little bit underneath it? Really spinning my wheels on this one and havent been able to find anything searching.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the css for div #page1:

```
#page1 {
    padding-top: 40px;
    height: 800px;
}
```

You need to add `padding-top: 60px;` on `#page2` for your about me page to display properly. You can change the size of the padding as you wish. You need to add the padding because you need to count for the height of the navigation bar when you jump to a part of the page with `id`. The browser will jump so that the div you are jumping to align exactly to the top of your window. But your navigation bar takes up 50px in height, which is why part of your div `#page2` is covered.

Here's my modification: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WoYmVq

--

Or, you can create an empty div with id #page2 before your current #page2 div, and change your current #page2 div to some other id/class. Give the #page2 div a height of 50px. Now when you click on "About me", you will jump to the empty #page2 div, which will be covered by your navigation bar

Here's a demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VmVNLx

Comment: But then when I scroll up, I see a bunch of red space from the padding. I was trying to get it to truly start at the beginning of the red. Is that possible?

Comment: Please see my edited answer for explanation. Yes it is possible. You can make an empty dive that takes up 50-60px in height, and name it with id page2 instead of the real div for page2.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and demo! Truly appreciate it. Demo really helped.

Comment: Hi @AngeloBravo if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.